# Ищу хорошую документацию по работе с svg файлами.

Tags: raphael, svg, javascript, html

Ищу хорошую документацию, по библиотеке snap.svg, или более удобную библиотеку для загрузки svg картинки и файла и дальнейшей работой над ней. Например имеется svg, котором нарисовано 2 объекта, нужно загрузить svg на сайт, и дальше используя какую - нибудь библиотеку, например, задать различную анимацию разным объектам.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: анимация в svg это javascript в основном. вроде rafael ничего библиотека, правда она немного крива, но нормально документирована. а документация к формату наверное на w3c.org должна быть

Answer (score 1):

[Аналогичный вопрос](https://toster.ru/q/85006#answer_273756). Ответ довольно информативный (с сылочной точки зрения).